# Dynamic form class for getting value from a form

Tags: php, oop

I'm using a `Form` class for getting the values of a form in static way. Everything is great. But I want to do it dynamically. I want a form class that will do the job for different forms. In display() method I'm getting value of name, email, password, phone etc. I want that when there are more or less value or in another form the Form class do the job for me dynamically. How can i do that?

```
//This is Register.php
public function display()
{
    Form::setname($_POST['name']);
    Form::email($_POST['email']);
    Form::password($_POST['pass']);
    Form::repassword($_POST['rpass']);
    Form::phone($_POST['phone']);

    list($name,$b,$c,$d,$e)=Form::getall();
}

<?php 
//This is Form.php
class Form
{
    private $name;
    private $email;
    private $pass;
    private $rpass;
    private $phone;

    public static function setname($name)
    {
        $this->name=$name; //  Using $this when not in object context 
    }

    public static function email($email)
    {
        $this->email=$email;
    }

    public static function password($pass)
    {
        $this->pass=$pass;
    }

    public static function repassword($rpass)
    {
        $this->rpass=$rpass;
    }

    public static function phone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone=$phone;
    }

    public static function getall()
    {
        $a=$this->name;
        $b=$this->email;
        $c=$this->pass;
        $d=$this->rpass;
        $e=$this->phone;
        return [$a,$b,$c,$d,$e];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine I just needed a setvalue and getvalue method in Form calss .And call it each time for a specific field in display() method.Is it good or there are any better way?

```
class Form{

private $value;

public  function setvalue($value)
{
    $this->value=$value;
}

public function getvalue()
    {
        $a=$this->value;
        return $a;
    }
}
public function display()
{
$newform=new Form();
$newform->setvalue($_POST['name']);
$name=$newform->getvalue();

$newform->setvalue($_POST['email']);
$b=$newform->getvalue();

$newform->setvalue($_POST['pass']);
$c=$newform->getvalue();
$newform->setvalue($_POST['rpass']);
$d=$newform->getvalue();
$newform->setvalue($_POST['phone']);
$e=$newform->getvalue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you have to do to get this right. First, avoid statics. Conceptually each form should be represented by it's own object. Second, use magic methods provided by PHP. Those are very powerful and if used properly can allow for some crazy good designs. Third, use array notation with a single name for all your input elements within a single form, for example, for the name of your form elements: use something like: `User[email]` instead of just `email` and `User[name]` instead of just `name` and so on and so forth.

Keeping these in mind, the form class could be as follows:

```
class Form{

    private $variables = array();

    public function __get($name){
        $returnValue = null;
        if(isset($this->variables[$name])){
            $returnValue = $this->variables[$name];
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value){
        $this->variables[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function getAll(){
        return $this->variables;
    }

}
```

This should be enough for the functionality that you require. In addition, you can add a convenience function that I have found very useful. This could be named as a `setAttrubites` or `setAll` function. It would be like this:

```
public function setAll($allData){
    foreach($allData as $key => $data){
        $this->variables[$key] = $data;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to set all variables in one swoop using a command like this:

```
$form = new Form();
$form->setAll($_POST['User']);
```

In order to make this possible, as I mentioned before, all your input elements should be grouped in an array. So the input elements would be like this:

```
<input type="text" name="User[name]" />
<input type="text" name="User[email]" />
```

Hope you get the drift...

Comment: Why should I use User[email] instead of just email ? @fijas

Comment: That is not necessary. It is just for convenience so that you don't have to individually assign all input fields to the object. This will allow you to do a massive assignment using the single line: `$form->setAll($_POST['User']);` as shown in my answer... You can also alternatively just do `$form->setAll($_POST);` but using the method in the answer will make the class more future proof...

Comment: You can up-vote an answer using the up arrow on the left side of the post. Additionally, you can accept an answer by clicking on the tick icon next to that answer. This post explains it in detail: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/232195

Comment: Ok I vote your answer.Now can you please explain me how __set and __get method actually work? @fijas

Comment: `__set` and `__get` are so called magic methods. You can read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php . There are a few more magic methods available in PHP. If you assign or retrieve a value to the property of an object and the property does not exist in the class, the set and get magic functions will be automatically called by PHP. In your question, as we might not know the actual properties of the class, we can make use of these methods to dynamically allow assigning and retrieving values via the object... This allows the class to be dynamic in nature as requested...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an array of new variables to the class, much like

```
$dynamic_form_elements = array();
public static function dynamic_element($element, $value) {
    $this->dynamic_form_elements[$element] = $value;
}
```

After that, simply put the $dynamic_form_elements variable to your list for returning in the getAll() method.

```
return [$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$dynamic_form_elements];
```